# How to get image to display using background-image: CSS in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to display an image in WordPress via CSS using `background-image` as I want to display different scaled images for mobile/desktop.

If I insert the image inline then it displays just fine. I do not want to display it inline as I want to serve different images for specific media queries. As such I am trying to display the image using: `background-image` with CSS.

I have made a new folder called `images` and moved the images I want from `uploads` to `images` which is in the same directory as `style.css`

The file pathway is: `wp-content/themes/resca-child/images`

I am using the following code in CSS:

```
.image1 {
background-image: url('/images/Homepage1-edited.png');
background: no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
max-height: 925px;
}
```

I have played around with different file pathways and CSS and I still can't get it to load. I'm guessing I have the wrong pathway precedence or something but I am not sure how to fix.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: <div class="image 1" src="http://... This is wrong. You cannot use src in a div.

Answer (score 3):

you can try an easy way you just have to put backgroud image i.e.

background-image: url('/images/Homepage1-edited.png');

in your inline style and add like this suppose image1 css apply on a div
so code should be

```
<div class="image1" style =" <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>background-image: url('/images/Homepage1-edited.png');">
```

now you can will whole path. It is very helpful when you want to add dynamic image because from css file you can't add dynamic image

I hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress have `style.css` and `images` folder in same path so you can use background image path like `images/Homepage1-edited.png`..

```
.image1 {
    background-image: url('images/Homepage1-edited.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `/` which is telling the system to look for the file in root :)

If your CSS was in a subdirectory, which is fairly standard, and you images were in an img directory, you would use `../images/Homepage1-edited.png` by the way.

But as you specify they are in the SAME directory, simply remove the slash.

Comment: I have tried and that doesn't work either. When I check in firebug the image loads when you hover the mouse over the inspector but the image still does not load. http://ec2-52-48-176-104.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Mate apart from anything else, you have 6016 pixel image loading on that site.... it's 4.3mb! Is THAT the image you can't load? Perhaps you are just not giving it time? ;)

Comment: That page weighs 33mb! I humbly suggest you have way more problems than this image not loading, perhaps your connection is even timing out waiting.

Comment: Indeed it is a large image. I am aware of the size but this is just a dev site. The image loads no problem when served inline or from the media folder. But, just for clarity I have swapped it out for a much smaller image and same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the background-image of below code :

1)  `<div class="image1" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Homepage1-edited.png);">`

OR

2) wp-content/themes/resca-child/style.css
add below code in child theme css

```
.image1 {
    background-image: url('images/Homepage1-edited.png');
}
```